# Pass a parameters to stateful class

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I pass a parameters to a stateful class in flutter?

I couldn't pass a parameter in the class as I'm a beginner and don't know the method.

I want to pass data from a list to build the class x times, and display the data in a container.

The text I want to pass is labeled tH.

I hope if someone can pass the argument for me.

My class:

```
class Thkr extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _ThkrState();
  }
}

class _ThkrState extends State<Thkr> {
  int Thkr_count = 3;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      Thkr_count--;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext) {
    return (Column(children: [
      Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(35),
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 3),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.lightGreen,
              offset: Offset(6.0, 6.0),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        child: Text({here I want to pass the data},
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: textSize, color: themeli[themei])),
      ),
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: [
          Card(
            child: SizedBox(
              width: 100,
              height: 30,
              child: Center(
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.lightGreen,
                      minimumSize: Size.fromHeight(40), //
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      _incrementCounter();
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      'Count',
                      style: TextStyle(color: themeli[themei]),
                    ),
                  )),
            ),
          ),
          Card(
            child: SizedBox(
              width: 100,
              height: 30,
              child: Center(
                  child: Text("$Thkr_count left",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        backgroundColor: Colors.white12,
                      ))),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )
    ]));
  }
}
```